# How to create volley header having 'Content-Type', Authorization Token and body?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am trying to create a login volley post request using custom server with oauth 2.0 using authentication token.
Body:

```
{
"customer": {
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "password":"12345"
  }
}
```

I tried this

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
       final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
       headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
       headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer .....UzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.....");
       headers.put("email",username.toString());
       headers.put("password",password.toString());
       headers.put("customer",headers.toString());

       Log.e("Json created", headers.toString());
       return headers;
}
```

Comment: body must be passed through another method getBody(). and here what you have done, return value will not be as expected.

Comment: Could you suggest any example ?

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this if you want to pass data as JSON body..

```
String body = "{\"customer\":{\"email\":"+ username + ",\"password\":"+ password +"}}";

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, response -> {
    //response here
}, error -> {
    //exceptions here
}) {
    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        return body.getBytes();
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        final HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer .....UzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.....");
        return headers;
    }
};
```